# Continuity test on potential-free contacts

Tags: gpio, input

When testing connections on working binary potential-free device Siemens N 262E01 I have accidently put continuity test between two contacts.  I analyzed continuity test, and found its maximum values to be 1V and 400uA.  I know you don't know specific of the device, but would such voltage/current in general destroy the input or maybe even the whole device?

[BTW: continuity test beeped, if that helps answering the question.]

Comment: The [data sheet](https://hit.sbt.siemens.com/RWD/modules/kernel/UI/slow/GetBinData.aspx?SID=A6V10416532&VALUE=Assets%5cA6V10416532_Binary%2520input%2520N%2520262E01_en.pdf&KEY=2&EXT=.pdf&TARGET=_blank&DTP=Data+Sheet+for+Product&RT=1590248611917) on that device says never put any voltage on it or it may destroy it. That’s rather vague, I would not think the continuity test could damage it - with a reasonably decent design for field use. Can you not just test the device functionality to make sure it has not been damaged?

Comment: @relayman357 I know, it was a stupid mistake.  Unfortunately, I cannot test it unless I call an authorized service.

Comment: @relayman357 In case you are interested: I have contacted Siemens support - they were very helpful and they replied "Such a small load can not destroy or damage the inputs from the N262."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted Siemens support - they were very helpful and they replied "Such a small load can not destroy or damage the inputs from the N262."